# Bcrypt Password encoder - grails

Tags: grails, bcrypt, password-encryption

I've read a post here about password encoder, and saw this syntax:

```
passwordEncoder.isPasswordValid(user.password, params.password, null)
```

I already used this in my grails project which has bcrypt password encryption plug-in and it works well.
I'm just curious what's the third parameter for which has a *null* value?
thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's for passing in a salt if you use one.

Comment: ...and you should *always* use a random salt.